NestJS Azure Web App Service architectural design
I need to handle access token creation and refreshing in an Azure web app service using NestJs. The generated access token is used by two endpoints within the service. I have several options as follows:
•   Simple TypeScript Class
•   Service
•   Middleware:
Here is the folder structure:
project root

auth folder
end point#1: includes service, module and controller files
end point#2: includes service, module and controller files
main.ts
module.ts

Which approach do you suggest to implement access token creation, cashing and refreshing. I understand using simple type script class may not integrate well with NestJS dependency injection. However I would like to know more about the challenges I face if I decide to take that approach.
If not simple typescript class, What do you think using middleware instead of service? What do I miss if I use middleware?

Passport is an authentication framework that can do that for you. There is a nestjs wrapper for it. I'm using @nestjs/passport with passport-azure-ad BearerStrategy.
@nestjs/passport provides an @AuthGuard() decorator which you can add to your controllers or endpoints.
There is a tutorial in the nestjs docs.

Nice to know about it. Yet, I like to stick to the basics and do it myself. You did not answer my question.
